# How to solve for y for a set of implicit (in x and y) linear equations for use in Plot?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, replacement, linear-algebra, rule

From a matrix `m={{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}`, a vector `b={1, 2}`, and a list of variables `vars={x,y}` we can generate a list of linear equations using the matrix equation `m.vars==b` which gives `{x+y,-x+y}=={1,2}`. How do I transform equations into `eqs={1-x,x+2}`? In other words how do I solve for `y = rhs` but only returning the rhs? I tried different things including picking parts with `Part` and `ReplaceAll` rules and transformations but none worked.

The reason I want equations in rhs form is that I figured out how to "visualize" linear equations using `Plot`. All other tutorials including Wolfram documentation and published books use `ContourPlot` or graphics primitives `Line` for this which I find too cumbersome for plotting the simplest of functions derived from matrix equations. With `Plot` it is very easy to do `Plot[eqs,{x,-10,10}]`.

Here is my code to facilitate a solution...

```
ClearAll[m,b,eqs,vars,x,y];
vars = {x,y};
m = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
b = {1, 2};
eqs = m.vars == b;
```

the solution should be equivalent to this...

```
eqs = {-x+1, x+2};
Plot[eqs, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want, but I am not sure that it is better than a `ContourPlot` approach in any meaningful way:

```
Plot[Evaluate[y /. First@Solve[#, y] & /@ Thread@eqs], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for coming through for me again. I will give your solution a green check mark (Accept) after giving others a a good full day to answer this.

Comment: @JulesManson You are very welcome!

Comment: I prefer `Plot` for its most natural appearance especially the axes placement and styles. Unless I am mistaken axes placement in `ContourPlot` tends to be on the frame which I don't like.

Comment: @JulesManson - `Frame` and `Axes` are options for all of the 2D plotting functions. If you don't like the defaults, specify your preferences, e.g., `eqs = Thread[m.vars == b]; ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqs, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Marco, to perhaps convince Jules that his misgivings about `ContourPlot[]` are unfounded, how about adding an example of using `ContourPlot[]` with the `Axes -> True` (and possibly also adding in `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio` to really match the look)?

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer,just a another thinking.

```
Clear["`*"];
m = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
vars = {x, y};
b = {1, 2};
eqs = m.vars - b // Evaluate;
ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, -10, 10}, {v, -10, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (Function[{x, y}, #] & /@ eqs), Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshShading -> {{LightYellow, LightGreen}, {LightCyan, LightBrown}}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}, 
 Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: that is beautiful work. i might steal that.